# How to Set Trailing Stop Loss? [Bybit API]

Tags: cryptography, cryptocurrency, bybit

I want to set a **trailing stop** loss for my "LONG" position.
*For example;* Can you show me how to make a trailing stoploss on USDT-M so that when the last price goes 10% above my entry price, it will follow the last price by 5%?
Thanks.

I tried to do it by trying the "Set Trading Stop" feature in the Bybit API document, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

This function is working.
For Example:

```
public static void SetTPSL (string symbol, string trailing_stop, string activate_price)
{
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "positionIdx", 0 },
            { "symbol", symbol },
            { "trailingStop", trailing_stop },
            { "activePrice", activate_price }
        };
    
        var responce = Request.SendRequest("/contract/v3/private/position/trading-stop", HttpMethod.Post, parameters);
}
```

In this case we placed Trailing stop at 1000 price and 5 point - correction